# Ipython notebook fails to produce plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

## The question:

Using an Ipython notebook, the following code fails to output a plot.  The same code, however, executed in a python console produces the desired plot.  Why does it fail to work in the notebook?

### Make a plot to display the results:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,4])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x,y,'o',label='Data',color=maps[0])
ax.plot(xfit,fit,'-',label='Best Fit',color=maps[0])
ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')
ax.set_ylabel('Relative Amount')
ax.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':8})
ax.set_ylim((-0.1,1.1))
ax.set_xlim((-0.5,10.5))
fig.tight_layout()
font = {'family' : 'sans-serif',
        'weight' : 'regular',
        'size' : '8'}
plt.rc('font',**font)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Did you add `%matplotlib inline` at the start of your notebook?

Comment: Ah man, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to include:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

at the beginning of the code.